# add row to a table using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to append a new row in a table with a variable

I used this line of code with no luck

```
 $('.view-payments table').append('<tr><td>Amount</td><td>' grandTotal '</td></tr>');
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 3):

it should be

```
$('.view-payments table').append('<tr><td>Amount</td><td>'+grandTotal+'</td></tr>');
```

Comment: Not quite: http://stackoverflow.com/a/171049/139010

Comment: Yes the '+' sign was the only issue otherwise it was correct.

Comment: Altough you should use below approach to append row in table dyanmic becuase its right way to add any row to table.

You can use following approach as well.

$('.view-payments table').append($('<tr>')
  .append($('<td>').append('Amount'))
  .append($('<td>').append(' + grandTotal + '))
);